# MySQL Removing Escaped Characters in JSON String

Tags: c++, mysql, json

I have a program that serializes some information into a JSON string, the string is then stored in a MySQL database. Then when the information is needed again it is loaded from the database and should be able to be loaded into a JSON object, but MySQL seems to be removing some escaped characters & messing up that process.

Here's a picture of the strings after the program finishes loading... The string titled "result" is the way the string is expected to be stored, but for some reason it's being stored as stored_string's version...
[image: https://i.imgur.com/ffKQYcP.png]

I'm using jsoncpp & MySQL5.7. The below DB & JSON files are simply wrapper classes i made.

Gah..... After googling for quite sometime I found some information that lead me to a function called mysql_real_escape_string. This should be called anytime we're inserting a string into the database (technically I guess).... It basically escapes characters so they are stored as is in the query. This is the step I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling for quite sometime I found some information that lead me to a function called mysql_real_escape_string.

This should be called anytime we're inserting a string into the database (technically I guess).... It basically escapes characters so they are stored as is in the query. This is the step I was missing.