# Remove escape symbols in string using mysql command

Tags: mysql, json, string, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL  column with data looking like this,

[image]

I need to convert the column to the `JSON` format via `convert(somecolumn,JSON)`. However, it seems that I first need to remove the escape symbols (e.g., `\"`). I did some search and found that `mysql_real_escape_string` will do the job (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600937/mysql-removing-escaped-characters-in-json-string)).

But if I understand correctly, `mysql_real_escape_string` is a PHP command. Is there any native MySQL command that do similar thing as `mysql_real_escape_string` (something like  `convert(mysql_native_function(somecolumn),JSON)`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace). For harder things REGEXP_REPLACE.

```
SELECT REPLACE(somecolumn, '\"', '"')
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('"..."', '(^"|"$)', '')
```

The latter will unquote the entire string, as `^` is the start, and `$` the end.

*BTW I would actually correct all the data in the table once. (After a backup.)*

Answer (score 0):

The **mysql** library is old.. if you really need to use something like it - use **mysqli**

the **mysql_real_escape_string** is not as secure as you would think it to be, see this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8028/does-mysql-escape-string-have-any-security-vulnerabilities-if-all-tables-using-l

That said you're much better off by not using any of them but using Php PDO and replacing something like:

```
$data = [
    'name' => $name,
    'surname' => $surname,
    'sex' => $sex,
];
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, sex) VALUES (:name, :surname, :sex)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
```

it will take care of the 'escaping' problems for you.

more examples here: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/insert